# Operator to call export menu

Tags: python

I have to create an operator to perform some tasks (manage selection / hide / unhide), and then call export menu.

I coded the following:

```
bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name="INFO_MT_file_export")
```

But I have "No filename given" when I choose the exporter, after menu displayed.

I know that if I want to call only 1 exporter, I have to give 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' to be able to choose file:

```
bpy.ops.wm.collada_export('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

But I don't know how to manage when I want to call the menu, not a specific exporter.

Any ideas ?

Edit : Here is example code : http://www.pasteall.org/75201